# PDF Data source in Informatica

Tags: pdf, informatica-powercenter

How does Informatica handle unstructured data sources like PDF? If a tabular report is stored as a PDF, can we read it out from PDF as a tabular data (like a data table in .NET)?

Answer (score 2):

**Informatica PowerCenter Unstructured Data Option**

- [PDF datasheet](http://www.informatica.com/INFA_Resources/ds_unstructured_data_6668.pdf)
- [website](http://www.informatica.com/us/products/enterprise-data-integration/powercenter/options/unstructured-data-option/)

Funny you mention it, I used to work for the start-up company that invented the underlying technology, until the acquisition with Informatica.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is actually quite structured internally. More recent revisions of the PDF specification may provide a way to hold the data ready for external processing, but the main goal of PDF documents is to describe a document for printing, so all kinds of environments and devices can print the document with a result as similar as possible.

It depends largely on the creator of the PDF if any extra data is provided other than where to print text and lines to form a table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Informatica B2B data exchange product which handles unstructured data. This product offers features to handle all kinds of unstructured data not only PDF but also Word, Excel,Star Office, AFP, PostScript, PCL, and HTML.  You would have to use Informatica B2B Data Transformation.

Here is quick link for your reference.

http://www.informatica.com/us/products/b2b-data-exchange/b2b-data-transformation/